# asp.net - "attribute 'language' is not a valid attribute of element 'script'" error

Tags: asp.net, xhtml, datepicker

I'm putting together a webpage with a datepicker. So far the datepicker has worked on other pages, but these don't have a master menu over the top of them. Code for the datepicker is below:

```
        <input type="text" ID="txtMSStart" runat="server" onkeypress="return ReturnNothing()"/>

        <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#txtMSStart").datepicker(
                {
                    showOn: 'button',
                    buttonImage: 'icon-calendar.jpg',
                    buttonImageOnly: true,
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                    showAnim: 'slideDown',
                    duration: 'fast'
                });
            });
        </script>
```

This is the same as the other datepickers. The ReturnNothing() function works and basically ensures that the user can't manually enter anything into the input box (apparently it needs to be an input box, and not a textbox, as I gather you can't add custom stuff like this to a textbox).

However, on my previous pages (which are all stand-alone pages, which don't have a master file) this works fine. In this case, however, it doesn't, and the only thing I can see which is different is that the

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
```

line brings up a warning, which is:

Validation (XHTML 1.1): Attribute 'language' is not a valid attribute of element 'script'

That's the only difference I can see. The box is there but no datepicker button appears next to it. Without the ReturnNothing() you can enter text manually into it.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The error that you get is because of the attribute 'language' that you specified in  tag. Therefore, just remove language="javascript" from  tag and that's it. Hope helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to do another work-around instead. Seems the datepickers only work on some pages and not others, and am against the clock on this one. So instead I've simply got two calendar controls (you've got to have a "from" date and "to" date) and am using them. Bit ugly, but it works for the moment.